# Google App Engine - Cannot See Children in Datastore Viewer

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have the following kinds/relationships in my datastore:

```
UserAccount 1-to-1 PersistentLogin 1-to-many PersistentLogins
```

They are all in the same entity group and UserAccount is the parent. Should I expect to see the other kinds in the datastore viewer? Currently, I only see UserAccount entities, but I'm pretty confident the other entities are there because my code is working as expected. Is this just a nuance of the datastore viewer?

Comment: This appears similar to the following issues on the GAE tracker: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1652 http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1756

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see them all in the datastore view, but only if they have at least one indexed property - kinds with no indexed properties don't currently show up (known bug).

Comment: I haven't explicitly defined any indexes, but all my kinds are using com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key as the @Id. Do I need to create a datastore-indexes.xml so they show up in the datastore viewer?

Comment: Not indexes, indexed properties - properties that aren't of type 'blob' or 'text', or specified as unindexed.

Comment: Interesting so if I add a property to each kind that just stores an integer w/ a hard coded 1 for each entity then it should show up?

Comment: I added an int property to each of my kinds that wasn't showing up in the datastore viewer and they still are not showing up.

Comment: Did you actually create any entities with that property? The datastore viewer can't 'see' your schema - it can only observe the properties in entities that actually exist.